# Evaluate the Legendre symbol $(\frac{14}{p})$ for $p > 2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

Let $p > 2$. I try to compute the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{14}{p}\right)$, but I have some difficulties. Here is my attempt so far:

$$\left(\frac{14}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{7}{p}\right).$$

$$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}} = \begin{cases}
    \ \ \ 1, & \text{if } p \equiv \pm 1\mod 8 \\
   -1, & \text{if }  p \equiv \pm 3\mod 8.
  \end{cases}$$

If $p$ is odd, $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{7-1}{2} \frac{p-1}{2}} \left(\frac{p}{7}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\frac{p}{7}\right)$,

where
$$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = \begin{cases}
    \ \ \ 1, & \text{if } p \equiv 1\mod 4 \\
   -1, & \text{if }  p \equiv 3\mod 4
  \end{cases}$$
and
$$\left(\frac{p}{7}\right) = \begin{cases}
    \ \ \ 1, & \text{if } p \equiv 1, 2, 4\mod 7 \\
   -1, & \text{if }  p \equiv 3, 5, 6\mod 7.
  \end{cases}$$

Applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem I obtain

$$\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = \begin{cases}
    \ \ \ 1, & \text{if } p \equiv \pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 9\mod 28 \\
   -1, & \text{if }  p \equiv \pm 5, \pm 11, \pm 13 \mod 28
  \end{cases}.$$

To multiply $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)$ I have to apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem again, but I don't see how to continue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: should use mod 56 to make room for the 8

Comment: for your question towards the end, there is only one even prime!

Comment: If $p$ is even, then $(7|p)$ isn't a Legendre symbol.

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks for your comment. I don't understand how to apply CRT, since $gcd(56, 8) \neq 1$.  Can you maybe show this to me ?

Comment: You say $(14/p)$ for $p>2$ and then ask $(14/2)$? I don't understand...

Comment: What @WillJagy said. You now know $(\frac2p)$ and $(\frac 7p)$ for all the possible residue classes of $p$  modulo $56$ (24 possibilities). The rest is just multiplying $\pm1$s together :-)

Answer (score 1):

If $\left(\frac{14}{p}\right)=1$ then

$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{7}{p}\right)$

We have:

$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1 \Longleftrightarrow p=1,7\pmod 8$

$\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)=1 \Longleftrightarrow p=1,3,9,19,25,27\pmod {28}$

(The calculations for $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)$ are done using the law of quadratic reciprocity.)

These congruences give $p= 1,9,25,31,47,55 \pmod {56}$
for half the set of primes.

The other half set is derived from:

$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=-1 \Longleftrightarrow p=3,5\pmod 8$

$\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)=-1 \Longleftrightarrow p=5,11,13,15,17,23\pmod {28}$

gives combined congrences:

$p= 5,11,13,43,45,51\pmod {56}$

Putting two and two together gets us:

$\left(\frac{14}{p}\right)=1 \Longleftrightarrow p=1,5,9,11,13,25,31,43,45,47,51,55\pmod {56}$

Answer (score 0):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol) we have
$$
{\displaystyle \left({\frac {n}{2}}\right)=\left\{{\begin{matrix}0&{\mbox{if }}n\equiv 0{\pmod {2}}\\1&{\mbox{if }}n\equiv 1,7{\pmod {8}}\\-1&{\mbox{if }}n\equiv 3,5{\pmod {8}}\end{matrix}}\right.} 
$$
Concerning your question "I try to compute the Legendre symbol $(\frac{14}{2})$", the answer is $0$, but as Kronecker symbol, since it is not a Legendre symbol.

Comment: Did I write $(\frac{14}{2})$ ? Sorry, then this was just a typo.